# Free usability questionnaire templates to follow?

Tags: usability, usability-testing, ux-designer

I am a programmer, and whilst I may know a lot about programming - I do not know a lot about UX or usability testing in general.

I plan to undertake a usability test on a website that I designed. Ideally, I want participants to fill in a questionnaire at the end of my test/study. However, I am struggling to find a free template to follow.

I have heard of Supr-Q and WAMMI. Which one is better to use for just a usability test. My website will not officially be launched, as I have other plans and commitments and this is just a change from my current field (I still do programming, but this has become like a part time hobby).

Both Supr-Q and WAMMI are not free. So how do I write a questionnaire following these standards? Also do I just copy and modify the questions?

Would appreciate it if someone could clarify this for me

Comment: What is your goal in the questionnaire at the end of the study?  What are you trying to learn in those questions that you think you might not learn during the course of the study?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious "free" alternative to Supr-Q & WAMMI would be the [System Usability Scale](http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/system-usability-scale.html).

This [article by Jeff Sauro on the SUS](http://www.measuringu.com/sus.php) is a reasonable introduction.

The reason you want to use a standard questionnaire, rather than just making one up or copying some questions, is that SUS, WAMMI, etc. have all been carefully produced so that we have a good model of how the results map onto the usability of the system. Random questions are unlikely to be useful in that way.

---

Also, if you're just doing some basic tests on your own site I don't think any of these questionnaires is going to give you much value to be honest.  They're useful in giving an indicator of how usable your product is — but that's usually very, very obvious from the usability test itself.

They can be useful in tracking progress over time. They can be useful if you're comparing multiple products. As a driver in improving your current product — not so much.

If you're new to usability testing I'd strongly recommend getting a copy of Steve Krug's "Rocket Surgery Made Easy". It's a quick read on some of the basics of running usability tests, written just for folk like you who are new to it and don't do it professionally.

Comment: Another good starting point is [Measuring the User Experience.](http://measuringuserexperience.com/) It discusses SUS, other scales, and other measurement methods.

Comment: ^ I second that recommendation.